# How to get user connection details on my website using JavaScript LinkedIn api?

Tags: javascript, php, linkedin-api

I am trying to get user connection details on my website using JavaScript LinkedIn api. Whenever I request the connection details it gives me this error in my console:

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections: 403 Forbidden.

This link opens an XML file.

I am receiving user basic profile details for eg: it's firstname, lastname, email address, no. of connections, headline, id etc but could not get its connection details. I made a little research and found out that I need to get an application permission from linked for getting the connection details. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

well you need refer LinkedIn developer **REST API** guide https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api#

Comment: Hi, the link is useful but it does not tell us about how to grant permission from linkedin for user connection details.

Comment: check this link below http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/using-linkedin-javascript-api-for-user-authentication-and-profile-retrieval.html

Comment: ya have worked on this but it only gives user basic profile details.When i use IN.API.Connections("me").result(); gives an error in console about access forbidden https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections: 403 Forbidden