# How to get LinkedIn permission for showing user connection details using LinkedIn JS API?

Tags: javascript, php, linkedin-api

I want to show user connection details along with the basic profile details on my website using LinkedIn JS API. I am getting the basic profile details but when requesting for connection details getting this error in my console:

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections: 403 Forbidden.

After doing a little research I found out that we need to get permission from LinkedIn for displaying user connection details. How will I be able to get the LinkedIn member's permission for displaying users connection details?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get user connection details on my website using JavaScript LinkedIn api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459396/how-to-get-user-connection-details-on-my-website-using-javascript-linkedin-api)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [LinkedIn API Docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition), the Connections API is only available to Partners.

> If your application is currently using any other API services (e.g. Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation, Job Search, etc.) you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program that provides the necessary API access to continue to leverage any of the endpoints that are not listed above.

You'll need to apply to join one of their Partner Programs to access that information.